# Sampling a bipartite graph on given set of vertices

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I want to sample a bipartite graph on a given set of vertices rather than just giving the number of vertices of each type like in sample_bipartite(n1, n2, p). To be more precise, I want to simulate a graph with two groups of vertices and create a graph by sampling vertices within each group and across those groups of vertices. My current code is:

```r
gw1 = sample_gnp(n1, p1, directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
n_e11=gsize(gw1)

E(gw1)$group <- rep(1,n_e11)

gw2 = sample_gnp(n2, p2, directed = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
n_e22=gsize(gw2)

E(gw2)$group <- rep(2,n_e22)
```

Next, I want to sample a bipartite graph between the vertices of `gw1` and `gw2`. Currently, I have written the following code to achieve this goal.

```r
gb12 = sample_bipartite(g_n[1], g_n[2], p = p[1,2])
n_e12=gsize(gb12)

E(gb12)$group <- rep(12,n_e12)
  
gw12 = gw1 + gw2
gg12 <- gb12 %u% gw12
  
E(gg12)$group_1[is.na(E(gg12)$group_1)] <- 0
E(gg12)$group_2[is.na(E(gg12)$group_2)] <- 0
E(gg12)$group <- E(gg12)$group_1 + E(gg12)$group_2
```

This gives me a graph I desire somehow, but I am not sure I am doing the right thing technically. If I could use the vertex set from the first two graphs to sample a bipartite graph, it would be technically what I want. I would appreciate if I can get some guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to simulate a graph with two groups of vertices and create a graph by sampling vertices within each group and across those groups of vertices

A graph that contains connections *within* the two groups as well is not [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), by definition.

You seem to be looking for `sample_sbm()`, which is like `sample_gnp()`, but we can specify a different `p` for each pair of groups, as well as within each group. You can have any number of groups.

Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_block_model

Comment: In sample_sbm() the vertices are assigned random to the groups. I need to create a graph where group membership is fixed in advance. I am trying to simulate a special case of SBM where vertex's group membership is fixed.

Comment: "In sample_sbm() the vertices are assigned random to the groups." No, they are not. Please read the documentation and the wikipedia link I gave you carefully.